# How do get my Apache server to recognize php_value in my .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7

I'm receiving the following error in my log files from my .htaccess file:

**.htaccess:** Invalid command **'php_value'**, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I am attempting to move a site from another server to my local Aquia Dev Desktop environment. So when I load the database and code and  I attempt to browse to the site. I get an **Internal Server Error**

In my my .htaccess file I have the follow settings being applied with php_value:

-php_value memory_limit 256M
-php_value memory_limit 512M
-php_value upload_max_filesize 192M
-php_value post_max_size 224M

-php_value session.cookie_lifetime 3600
-php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
-php_value max_execution_time 2400
-php_value max_input_time 300

Seems like it cant recognize the php_value command. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you added AllowOverride All in your apache configuration for the directory with the .htaccess file?

Comment: Not certain. Let me check the config now.

Comment: Yes. But its set on the parent directory of the .htaccess file. not the exact directory in which it resides.

Comment: That should not matter.